# How to run a script that it has to connect 3 solaris servers, do some operations and create files in the machine where the script is running?

Tags: bash, ssh, ftp, solaris

I have to do some task of migration of three solaris servers, I have the ip addresses, username and password for each server. The script that I have to run, it does what it has to do with no problems, but is created to run if the script and the directory needed are in the same machine, so I have to change it adding the necesary connections instructions, but I am very limited for the next reasons:

- I am not allowed to change or install anything on these systems.
- I am allowed only to read privileges with the users I have.
- The output files should be generated in the machine where the script is running, that leave to the next point.
- The script it has to be run in a Solaris machine with a bash version 3, so I do not know what versions of ftp or ssh commands work in this version of Solaris.

I only need the part of code that does the connection and search of the needed directory, Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the input and the output of that script? It reads a directory and creates a single output file?

Comment: The input: the script receives one string with a datetime format as first parameter and receives the name of a file as second parameter as following: ./script.sh 201301311212 file.txt
The second parameter is in the machine where the script is located. Then the script has to search in each server the files in a specified directory
the Output:
the script generates a file with a list as result of operations of substrings (according with the file in the second parameter) in the machine where the script is, not in the servers

Answer (score 1):

Use [sshfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) to mount the needed directories of your three servers.

Afterwards you can run the script locally accessing the remote data as local files.

Comment: This is the best answer you'll find.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I implement that command making an automatic script? Because the files that it need to process are big, with millions of lines, so the idea is create an automatic script to let it run it for a night (or more) without any pause to input a password or anything else

Comment: @michas and what implementation of sshfs exists for Solaris ?

Comment: The idea is mounting all the remote directories on one single host. For the host it looks like all the files are local, which seems to be a requirement for your script. According to a quick google it is possible to install sshfs on solaris. However it is not installed by default. If you are forced to run the script on a dedicated solaris host and you are not allowed to install anything, you are probably out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use pdsh (parallel distributed shell) to run the script on the 3 Solaris servers.